# How do I turn on line numbers by default in TextWrangler on the Mac?

Tags: macos, textwrangler

I am fed up having to turn them on every time I open the application.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Go to TextWrangler > Preferences.

Choose Text Status Display in the category pane, then check the option "Show line numbers"  and close the preferences. This should now be on by default when you open existing documents.